# Getting a cell.contentView height in cellForRowAtIndexPath to create a gradient background

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am have tableview where i have a gradient background for each cell and it works when the cells are the same size.  I use the same tableview for another dataset and variable cell sizes.  If i put the gradient code inside custom cell's initwithcoder then it creates a gradient for the size of the original cell.  I tried different things but wasn't able to get the right size.  The only answer was to create a temp frame with inside cellForRowAtIndexPath with the height of cell coming from a method that calculates it based on the text.  I am trying to figure out why the cell's height is not correct inside cellForRowAtIndexPath.  Here is the code to make it clearer.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
             cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                            object:(PFObject *)object 
    { 
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"feedCell";
        FeedTableViewCell *cell = (FeedTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[FeedTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:999]removeFromSuperview];
        // Configure the cell...
        UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16.0];
        cell.signText.font = cellFont;
        CGRect lblFrame = cell.signText.frame;
        lblFrame.size.height = [self labelHeightForText:[object objectForKey:@"text"]];
        cell.signText.frame = lblFrame;
        cell.signText.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        cell.signText.text = [object objectForKey:@"text"];
        UIColor *grayLightOp = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.863 green:0.841 blue:0.812 alpha:1.000];
        CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
//here is the tempFrame that i am talking about i can't just set tempFrame = cell.contentView.frame
        CGRect tempFrame = CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.origin.x, cell.contentView.frame.origin.y, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, [self labelHeightForText:[object objectForKey:@"text"]]);
        gradient.frame = tempFrame;
        gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor, (id)grayLightOp.CGColor, nil];
        UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:gradient.frame];
        backgroundView.tag = 999;
        [backgroundView.layer insertSublayer:gradient above:0];
        [cell.contentView insertSubview:backgroundView atIndex:0];
        [cell.backgroundView setNeedsDisplay];
        return cell;
    }

    -(CGFloat)labelHeightForText:(NSString *)text
    {
        UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16.0];
        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
        CGSize labelSize = [text sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        return labelSize.height + 20;
    }

    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        PFObject *feedObject = [self objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSString *cellText = [feedObject objectForKey:@"text"];
        return [self labelHeightForText:cellText];
    }
```

======Update 
I commented out the creating of gradient in cellForRowAtIndexPath and here is the code from the custom cell.  I guess i have to resize the gradient itself and not the background view.  When i do this the gradient size is right but when i scroll i see this quick animation of gradient being drawn when the cell comes in view.  Can i do something about that?

```
@interface FeedTableViewCell()

@property (nonatomic, strong)CAGradientLayer *cellGradient;

@end

@implementation FeedTableViewCell

@synthesize signText = _signText;
@synthesize personName = _personName;
@synthesize personImageView = _personImageView;
@synthesize cellGradient = _cellGradient;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self) {
        UIColor *grayLightOp = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.863 green:0.841 blue:0.812 alpha:1.000];
        self.cellGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];

        self.cellGradient.frame = self.contentView.frame;
        self.cellGradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor, (id)grayLightOp.CGColor, nil];
        UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.cellGradient.frame];
        backgroundView.tag = 998;
        [backgroundView.layer insertSublayer:self.cellGradient above:0];
        self.backgroundView = backgroundView;
        //[self.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
    self.cellGradient.frame = self.contentView.frame;
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

// update with new code with out the backgroundview

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self) {
        UIColor *grayLightOp = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.863 green:0.841 blue:0.812 alpha:1.000];
        CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
        gradient.frame = self.frame;
        gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor, (id)grayLightOp.CGColor, nil];
        /*UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:gradient.frame];
        [backgroundView.layer insertSublayer:gradient above:0];
        self.backgroundView = backgroundView;
        [backgroundView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];*/
        [self.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the gradient layer once, ideally in your cell's init method. Resize it in the cell's `layoutSubviews` method (calling `super` first).

The way you are doing it now will give poor scrolling performance as you are recreating a gradient layer each time.

The code in your updated question is nearly OK, but you can see the animation of the gradient resizing. This is because you are changing an animatable property of a CALayer - these changes are animated by default. You can prevent this by wrapping the change in a CATransaction and disabling implicit animations:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    NSArray *layers = [self.backgroundView.layer sublayers];
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [layers objectAtIndex:0];

    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
    gradient.frame = self.contentView.frame;
    [CATransaction commit];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I updated the question with code from the custom cell.  I don't see any performance hit when i scroll but i would rather make it work through drawing the gradient in the init.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!  This is a much better and cleaner solution.  Just one question.  Will the gradient always be layer's objectAtIndex:0? I am doing insertSublayer:gradient above:0]; Can that set the gradient to be layer greater then 0?

Comment: Personally I'd have a property or ivar on the cell to hold the gradient layer. Then it doesn't matter where it is in the hierarchy.

Comment: Thats a good idea.  Would work better and don't have to worry about layers.  I updated the code in the original code with having a property set. Please let me know if it's right.  Thanks!

Comment: That looks fine! You can probably get away without needing the background view, and just add it as a sublayer to the content view, but if what you have works, leave it.

Comment: I am learning layers now and i think i don't actually need to create a backgroundview here but just set the layer atindex:0 to the gradient layer.  I updated the original answers please let me know if this is right. The text from the table cell comes out on top of this layer.  Thank you!

Comment: And one more question if you don't mind.  If i add the gradient layer to the backgroundview.layer then the gradient doesn't come out.  How can i explain that.  Thanks again and Happy Holidays!!!

Comment: I think trying different things i kinda answered my own questions.  I can't just add a layer to backgroundview because it starts out to be nil.  I have actually have to init a view and make it equal to a backgroundview.  Also if insert gradient layer to self.layer then when i press on the table cell i don't see the selection color.  Please let me know if ia am understanding it correctly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot going on here, but your frame origin is wrong in this case. You set gradient's position to contentView position, but that position is relative to contentView's parent, and what you actually want is to start *inside* contentView at 0,0. You can use `contentView.bounds` as your frame, since that gives you only the size, position is 0.

Another thing I would check is autoresizing mask on gradient view, in case it's not resized when tableview applies new frame to the cell.